# Running a Selenium script only if a certain element is present

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

I have an if else statement nested in a for loop and I am trying to figure out a way to only run the program for the current feature (u) if the element exists. The element in question is a value in a select/option format.  Basically, I need a certain option in that drop down menu to be present for the code to run and if it is not I would like to move onto the next url and try again.  The option is either present or it's not (it won't pop up if the driver waits).

```
for u in urls:
    bot.get(u)
    if *statement to check if the value exists*:
       -- runs my intended function --
    else:
        print("This site is not reporting yet")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the *urls* and check if the value exists within a `try-catch{}` block and you can use the following solution:

```
for u in urls:
    try:
        bot.get(u)
        #check if the value exists using WebDriverWait with expected_conditions as visibility_of_element_located
        #runs my intended function
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("This site is not reporting yet")
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To follow up, I have "from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By", "from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait" and "from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC".  I'm getting a few errors because the "type object 'By' has no attribute 'Value' "(The dropdowns only have Values, no IDs or Names), and a NameError because "name 'TimeoutException' is not defined".  Am I running it as EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.Value, "my_value"))? Or bot.visibility_of_...?

Comment: I actually believe I just fixed the TimeoutException error with from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, But now I'm also wondering if it will be a "TimeoutException" or a "NoSuchElementException".

Comment: `WebDriverWait` on failure will always raise `TimeoutException`, so you need `selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`